# thread 1 exc_bad_instruction.. Error with swift

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading, swift3, xcode8

I'm in need of some serious help. I'm trying to create a database in my Xcode project with the help of Firebase, but I keep getting the same exact error after the build succeeds and then closes giving me this error :

> thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Any idea what this is about?

Here's the line of code that the error is on.

```
let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2)as! UILabel
```

Here's all of the code

```
    //
//  Database.swift
//  intern
//
//  Created by Lani  Daniels on 8/20/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Lani  Daniels. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct PostStruct {
        let title: String
        let message: String
    }



class DatabaseViewController: UITableViewController {

    var posts: [PostStruct] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("Posts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in

            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let title = snapshotValue?["title"] as? String

            let message = snapshotValue?["message"] as? String

            self.posts.insert(PostStruct(title: title ?? "", message: message ?? ""), at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
        post()
    }
    func post(){

        let title = "Title"
        let message = "Message"

        let post : [String : AnyObject] = ["title" : title as AnyObject, "message" : message as AnyObject]

         let databaseRef  = Database.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(post)
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1)as! UILabel
        label1.text=posts[indexPath.row].title

        let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2)as! UILabel // Error code: thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)
        label2.text=posts[indexPath.row].message 
        return cell

    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that cell has a label with tag = 2 ?? try `?` instead of `!` to make it optional `let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel
label2?.text=posts[indexPath.row].message`. If that doesn't crash it mens your cell don't have any child label with tag 2.

Answer (score 0):

thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0) error means that the app already determined that the elements should exists, so it will crash when it doesn't

in your case, there might be 2 reasons why is this happening:

1. please check whether view which tagged with "2" is an UILabel.
2. please check whether view which is tagged with "2" is exist.

The reason of crashing should be either one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The line :

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
```

means you are returning an UITableViewCell. The default style which is basic does not have 2 labels. So either change the dequeReusableCell to return your custom cell:

```
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? MyCustomCellView {
//MyCustomCellView would be your UITableViewCell implementation
    let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1)as! UILabel
    label1.text=posts[indexPath.row].title

    let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2)as! UILabel 
    label2.text=posts[indexPath.row].message 
}
```

Or change the cell style to **subtitle**  (so that you may be getting the second label)